# Choosing lexer mode based on variable

Tags: antlr4

My lexer (target language C++) contains a simple rule for parsing a string literal:

```
STRING: '"' ~'"'+ '"';
```

But based on the value returned by a function, I want my lexer to return either a STRING or an IDENT.

I've tried the following:

```
STRING_START:  '"'  -> mode(current_string_mode());
```

or

```
STRING_START:  '"'  -> mode(current_string_mode() == IDENT ? MODE_IDENT : MODE_STRING) ;
```

In either case, I get an error when trying to generate the lexer (error message says:`'"' came as a complete surprise`)

Answer (score 1):

Alas, that is not possible.

If I look at [the grammar of ANTLR itself](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr/antlr4/ANTLRv4Parser.g4), I see this:

```
lexerCommands
   : RARROW lexerCommand (COMMA lexerCommand)*
   ;

lexerCommand
   : lexerCommandName LPAREN lexerCommandExpr RPAREN
   | lexerCommandName
   ;

lexerCommandName
   : identifier
   | MODE
   ;

lexerCommandExpr
   : identifier
   | INT
   ;
```

In short: the part between parenthesis (`mode(...)` or `pushMode(...)`) must be an identifier, or an integer literal. It cannot be an expression (what you're trying to do).